Switching electric hob to induction hob
I’m wanting to switch my electric hob to an induction hob. The electric hob is on a dedicated circuit. Photos of the current electric hob and the ’to be installed’ induction hob as well as the circuit breaker.
Is this just a standard switch or do I need an electrician to change out wiring or breaker? Thank you.




Your old one states 6600 Watts, your new one is 7.35 kilowatts, or 7350 Watts. The 32 amp breaker, and perhaps (likely) the wiring, is not compatible with the new stove.

Will need to check if the breaker and the wires need upgrading.  Possible they can handle the extra power, but most people put in the minimum size required, just big enough to handle the power safety.  Do not know how to read the breaker, so unknown if it is already below power needed(6000) for old unit(6600), or just a non useful number(to me).

@JonCuster   At 220v it will be small, but 230/240 it should be okay, maybe.  Depends on how well they obey code.  32x230 is 7360.  Touchy for safety.  Cooktops are funny, that 7350 is for full power(christmas/thanksgiving) cooking.

And ignores the 80% derate, but I’m not up on European code requirements and if they have that concept.

Cooktops don't get an 80% derate in the US. In the UK there's no such concept AFAIK, you can run 32A on a 32A breaker.

This will depend more on applicable rules in your specific location than anything else (or perhaps a power limiting option found in the hob manual, actually, for induction hobs which can sometimes be a bit "smart" so maximum power can be reduced.) At 240V it would supply 7.68KW if derating isn't a thing under local rules. 7.36KW at 230 which sounds rather like the hob is designed for 32A breaker at 230 with no derate being 10W less. 7.04KW at 220V...

I’m in the UK, so I guess derate isn’t an issue, right?

Thank you all… looks like I should hire an electrician just to be safe.
